# Why can't I call my app "Parking" ? (unable to run app)

Tags: xcode

I created an app called "Parking" and when I try to run it (in Xcode), I am getting this error :
**"Unable to run app in Simulator"** *(that's the iOS simulator)*
`An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)`

I tried to delete this project, and create another one with the same name... nothing changed.
But choosing another name makes it work, even just changing the name of the target works, but whenever I get back to "Parking", it doesn't work anymore.

**EDIT : I am able to run my app on real iOS device, but still not on the iOS simulator :'(**

**How is such a thing possible ?**

Comment: I guess it's because there is already app with such bundle name, so yours is duplicate

Comment: @maxpovver Do you mean an app in the App Store ?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no restrictions to app names in the simulator. Have you tried resetting the simulator content and settings? Try that and run the parking app again

Comment: yes, as I know it's forbidden to name your app the same as someone elses.

Comment: For what it's worth (not much), it's some kind of conflict in your setup.  That name certainly isn't reserved in any way in my environment as of a couple of minutes ago!  What's your full bundle ID?

Comment: @PhillipMills com.example.parking

Comment: @maxpovver As bosman pointed out, it doesn't seem to be any restriction of this kind in the iOS simulator.

Comment: @Bosman I tried it, but it didn't changed anything... :/

Comment: try change com.example to something else, this might help

Comment: @maxpovver Tried to change it to "me" and to "com.me" but it didn't changed anything either.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise I have had this problem if there is a conflict of apps in the simulator. For example if I created an app called parking and ran that and then create another project and call the app the same it often doesn't allow me to run it. To resolve this I had to completely reset the cache, settings and content. And only have one project open. Hope that helps

Comment: @Bosman When you say "I had to completely reset the cache, settings and content", are you speaking about Xcode ?

Comment: No the actual simulator.you can look at this https://github.com/michaelpatzer/ResetAllSimulators

Comment: @Bosman I don't like too much running scripts like that, isn't it risky ?

Comment: @Bosman Actually I am able to run my app on a real iOS device.